# How to show listview.builder from right side of the list?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I have a horizontally scrollable listview.builder in my flutter code. I want to show this list from the right side of the list on screen. Is there any way to do that?

Look at the attachment. I have the first row initially. But I am wanting the second row initially.

[image: picture]

Here is the code:

```
ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,           
         itemCount: 7,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {}
)
```

Though I have tried `reverse:true` but did not worked.

Comment: Can you include an image what are you trying to build and code-snippet what you’ve tried so far?

Comment: Can you see the image I have attached?

Comment: Yes, and I hope bellow post answer your question.

Comment: No, there is some problem. I have told that on that post.

Comment: Consider including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You like to go to the end of the list initially, check `maxScrollExtent` answer

Answer (score 1):

**Wrap it with [Directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html)**

example:

```
Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: _myListViewBuilder(),
      ),
```

you can test it this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=83f3cc061baabb4136ce6e59411a83fa)

[image]

Comment: I do not want to reverse the list.

Comment: @AshrafulAlam you mean you want to scroll from right to left while having the zero on the right-end of the list (not show in the screen) ?

Comment: I want to scroll from right to left while having the zero on the left end of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add reverse to the listview

```dart
Listview(
  reverse: true,
  shrinkWrap: true,
)
```

The issue is the list by itself is getting reversed.. you can add a physics to listview

```dart
SingleChildScrollView (
  reverse: true,
  child: Listview.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true
    physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  )
)
```

Comment: Nope. It's showing list from backward. Like if the list 1,2,3,4 then using reverse: true the list becomes 4,3,2,1. I am wanting the list 1,2,3,4 but the screen should focus on 1<-2,3,4 rather than 1,2,3->4. Look at the image I have attached.

Comment: Also add shrinkwrap

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **scroll controller** and set the extent of the scrolling to the maximum in the **initState**.

Answer (score 0):

Creat a ScrollController and initialize it's scroll position in the init state, like:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp){
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
});
```

Then your build method can look like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 200.0,
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: 8,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Align(
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
                    color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(
                      Colors.primaries.length,
                    )],
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Result:
[image]